# Bottom off the site is cut off when scroll is up

Tags: html, css

I have tried so many iterations but I dont know what to do.

When I change top:0px in kontener and add margin:42px in  kontener_auto_2 bottom site is ok but upper scroll and  kontener is under nav.

Effect I want to achieve is scroll is under #nav but you see all scroll.

```css
html {

  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;

}

body {

  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;

}

#nav {

  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  z-index: 99;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #4d93d1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 10px 11px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -2px 10px 11px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -2px 10px 11px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);

}

#kontener {
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1F1F1F;

}

#kontener_auto {

  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  
  
}


#kontener_auto_2 {

  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(182px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
   

}

#tumble {
 
  float: left;
  height: 180px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: red;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="temp.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="nav"></div>
    <div id="kontener">

      <div id="kontener_auto">

        <div id="kontener_auto_2">

          <div id="tumble"></div>
          <div id="tumble"></div>
          <div id="tumble"></div>
          <div id="tumble"></div>
          <div id="tumble"></div>
          <div id="tumble"></div>
          <div id="tumble"></div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

I really need help but I don’t know how to achieve my dream effect.

Comment: Try removing `position: fixed;` from the html rule set.

Comment: i removed but nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

I fix it adding height:calc(100% - 42px); to kontener_auto and now is look nice.